# Custom NER on Spacy3.0 - ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

I am trying to train Spacy3.0 to recognize new naimed entity. I do exactly as specified in this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-spacy-3-0-to-build-a-custom-ner-model-c9256bea098

```
for text, annot in tqdm(TRAIN_DATA): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    
    for i in annot["entities"]:
        start = i[0]
        end = i[1]
        label = i[2]
 
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents
    db.add(doc)
db.to_disk(r"train.spacy") # save the docbin object
```

And everything works untill I add several ner to "ents".

For example: -Dad buy Apple- works ok. But -Dad buy Apple and Sumsung- doesn't work.

I get an error:
"Aborting and saving the final best model. Encountered exception: ValueError()"
File "spacy\pipeline_parser_internals\ner.pyx", line 310, in spacy.pipeline._parser_internals.ner.BiluoPushDown.set_costs
ValueError

Maybe something should be changed in config.cfg, but I can not find what.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `config.cfg`, but I don't see it used in your code. How have you defined your `nlp` model, and `TRAIN_DATA`?

Since spaCy v3, it is recommended to use the CLI command [`spacy train`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#train) rather than implementing custom training loops, which may be more brittle. There's a more detailed migration guide here: https://spacy.io/usage/v3#migrating

Looking at the error you're getting, it seems like perhaps the model is encountering a named entity type that was not defined in the training dataset?

I'm not sure though, because I can't follow exactly what is going on, and I don't know what you mean by "untill I add several ner to 'ents'". Would you be able to provide a minimal reproducable code snippet? That would be helpful to help you debug this.